# Playing sound with the PC Speaker in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, audio, x86, operating-system

So I'm trying to play a single tone using the pc speaker in x86 assembly, It play a sound, but when I try to turn it off again... the tone begins do what I can only describe as shaking.

Also I'm making this for a 16 bit OS if that means anything.

Here's my sound.asm file

```
; ------------------------------------------------------------------
; os_play_sound -- Play a single tone using the pc speaker
; IN: CX = tone, BX = duration

os_play_sound:
    mov     al, 182
    out     0x43, al
    mov     ax, cx

    out     0x42, al
    mov     al, ah
    out     0x42, al
    in      al, 0x61

    or      al, 00000011b
    out     0x61, al

    .pause1:
        mov cx, 65535

    .pause2:
        dec cx
        jne .pause2
        dec bx
        jne .pause1

        in  al, 0x61
        and al, 11111100b
        out 0x61, al

        ret
```

And here's the part in main.asm where I'm calling the sound.asm label from

```
mov cx, 9121
mov bx, 25
call os_play_sound
```

Comment: What are you testing this on? How long does it take for your delay loop to complete on that system?

Comment: I'm using qemu to test it, and if you by the delay loop mean the time it takes before it reaches ret... less then a second.

But, if I increase bx to let's say 75, there's sound... but it doesn't stop again

Comment: Using cycle-timed code is generally a pretty bad idea. Better to use some sort of hardware timer to implement a delay that doesn't depend on the CPU clock.

Comment: Okay so I can get to work as a timer... but, when it's supposed to stop, the sound begins to do what sounds like shaking

Comment: Well, maybe you have a bug elsewhere in your code that causes you to make incorrect writes to port 0x61.

Comment: @Michael So I tried to make a clean asm file to test if it was my code there was something wrong with. But it still happened.

I'm trying to make it for a 16 bit OS... don't know if that helps with anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm kind of late to the party and probably you may have figured it out, but here's my answer for the future StackOverflow lurking generations ;).

You can test the following snippet (based on your code; slightly cleaned up) that will in fact issue the tone, but wait using `INT15H` function `AX=86H`. It's usually a better practice than busy wait, but slightly worse than reprogramming the PIT for your needs. As you're using MikeOS though as your main codebase, I wanted to keep the code as simple as possible. Comments are included for further understanding of the code.

```
; ---------------------------------------------
; Generate tone with frequency specified in AX.
; The tone will last for CX:DX microseconds.
; For instance, CX=0, DX=F4240h will play the
; specified tone for one second.
; Registers preserved.

tone:
    PUSHA               ; Prolog: Preserve all registers
    MOV BX, AX          ; 1) Preserve the note value by storing it in BX.
    MOV AL, 182         ; 2) Set up the write to the control word register.
    OUT 43h, AL         ; 2) Perform the write.
    MOV AX, BX          ; 2) Pull back the frequency from BX.
    OUT 42h, AL         ; 2) Send lower byte of the frequency.
    MOV AL, AH          ; 2) Load higher byte of the frequency.
    OUT 42h, AL         ; 2) Send the higher byte.
    IN AL, 61h          ; 3) Read the current keyboard controller status.
    OR AL, 03h          ; 3) Turn on 0 and 1 bit, enabling the PC speaker gate and the data transfer.
    OUT 61h, AL         ; 3) Save the new keyboard controller status.
    MOV AH, 86h         ; 4) Load the BIOS WAIT, int15h function AH=86h.
    INT 15h             ; 4) Immidiately interrupt. The delay is already in CX:DX.
    IN AL, 61h          ; 5) Read the current keyboard controller status.
    AND AL, 0FCh        ; 5) Zero 0 and 1 bit, simply disabling the gate.
    OUT 61h, AL         ; 5) Write the new keyboard controller status.
    POPA                ; Epilog: Pop off all the registers pushed
    RET                 ; Epilog: Return.
```

Comment: @DanielBandeira looks like NASM code